# Multilingual HTML page with PHP - how to add titles to links

Tags: php, html, multilingual

I implemented text switching system as portrayed here http://www.bitrepository.com/php-how-to-add-multi-language-support-to-a-website.html .

Every link is defined like so:

```
<li><a href="#"><?php echo $lang['MENU_REGISTER']; ?></a></li>
```

By this logic, adding a title/description to a link would work like so:

```
<a title=<?php echo $lang['MENU_REGISTER']; ?> href="#">
<?php echo $lang['MENU_REGISTER']; ?></a>
```

I'm under impression that this does not work the way as I wish it would. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing opening and closing quotes:

```
title="<?php echo $lang['MENU_REGISTER']; ?>"
```

and preferably `addslashes` for other quotes:

```
title="<?php echo addslashes($lang['MENU_REGISTER'];) ?>"
```